# Problem with video url from ad manager

Tags: videos

I have a problem and I don't know what to do..
I am trying to insert VAST video (with URL) from Ad Manager in a wordpress site. 
I tried with iframe, with video tag element, with script as “src=” but it doesn’t show something. Is there any idea why?

Also it gives a warning in console about CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?... with MIME type text/plain ) 
when I use https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?...”>

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress supports the following video file types:

> .mp4, .m4v (MPEG-4),
>       .mov (QuickTime),
>       .wmv (Windows Media Video),
>       .avi,
>       .mpg,
>       .ogv (Ogg),
>       .3gp (3GPP),
>       and .3g2 (3GPP2)

[From the "Uploading Files" Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files#About_Uploading_Files_on_Dashboard).

If it's not in the list, you'll have to either add support or find a way to insert it manually which is what it sounds like you've done.

Also, the default WordPress editor doesn't allow iframed content. It gets stripped out when you publish.

If you're getting an error about cross-origin content, I recommend reading up on [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). There are a bunch of details that could cause an error like this which aren't covered in the scope of this community.